# Possible calculations with temperature, humidity, images and VIS spectrum of a plant in an Integrating sphere

Tags: physiology, botany, measurement

I am currently working on a project which involves growing some plants in a integrating sphere made of foam. I have added temperature, humidity and soil moisture sensors as well as a Spectrometer (350 - 800nm) and a webcam which takes images of the plant every 30 minutes.

I thought of calculating the LAI (Leaf area index) from the webcam images.

Does anyone have any other suggestions/ideas on what I could calculate with the given data from these sensors?

Comment: Are you designing an analysis around the data or have you gathered data to do an analysis? In other words, do you have a goal with this experimental set up?

Comment: Both. I have already gathered some data from a previous set up, but only with the spectrometer and webcam. The main goal is to observe water stress in different plants.  I curious what else i could calculate and predict once i have the data from the new set up.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Perhaps you could add this background to the question proper. Regardless, +1, thanks and welcome to Biology!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the images you could, perhaps, assess growth rate of the plant which can be plotted against spectral content of light to investigate effects of light quality on growth. Using moist and water and temperature the same can be done. Multivariate analysis can help to implement all the values, while ANCOVA may may help to correct for covariance.

A detailed experimental set up may help to answer this question. Not specifically the hardware, but how the effect of water stress is measured. E.g., are multiple plants tested under different watering conditions? In that case all the other measures (temperature, light) are probably used to check whether everything is constant across all specimens except water availability. This may limit the usefulness of analysis of these additional measures. I think the other parameters (light, water, temperature) may be not so interesting other than covariates for water stress as they are either not controlled or deliberately kept constant. Moreover, probably their effects on plants are pretty obvious too.